# Rounding up Decimal places varies

Tags: javascript, rounding

I am getting I believe to be an odd rounding of decimal places.
I am using the + cast to cast a string returned by .toFixed() to a number.
I have some test's and added numbers to them for clarity. I am curious about `Test 1` and `Test 3`

The first test works as expected - expects a rounding up of 2 decimal places.

The third however, looks odd to me, shouldn't it also be rounding up to `123.4600` ?

---

### **All tests are passing**

---

### Tests

```
var module = require("../../tests/yootil/Utilities.js");

// yootil.Utilities.stringToNumber
//
describe('yootil.Utilities.stringToNumber', function(){
  
  // TEST 1
  it('Should return a number with 2 decimals', function(){
    expect(module.yootil.Utilities.stringToNumber("123.4585")).toEqual(123.46);
  });
  
  // TEST 2
  it('Should return a number with zero decimal places', function(){
    expect(module.yootil.Utilities.stringToNumber("123.4585", 0)).toEqual(123);
  });
  
  // TEST 3
  it('Should return a number with 4 decimals', function(){
    expect(module.yootil.Utilities.stringToNumber("123.4587", 4)).toEqual(123.4587);
  });
  
  // TEST 4
  it('Should return null with an invalid string', function(){
    expect(module.yootil.Utilities.stringToNumber("test")).toEqual(null);
  });
  
  // TEST 5
  it('Should return null with NO parameters', function(){
    expect(module.yootil.Utilities.stringToNumber()).toEqual(null);
  });
  
  
});
```

### Module

```
var yootil = {};

yootil = (function(module){
  
  module.Utilities = {
    /**
     * Converts a string representation of a number 
     * to a number with decimal places.
     *
     * <example>
     *   var yo = yootil.Utilities; // create a cached version
     *
     *   yo.stringToNumber() // null
     *   yo.stringToNumber("12.3849") // 12.38
     *   yo.stringToNumber("123.3849", 0) // 123
     *   yo.stringToNumber("test") // null
     * </example>
     *
     * @param {string} string A number string
     * @param {int} Decimal places
     * @return {boolean}  
    **/
    stringToNumber: function(string, decimal_places){
      try{
        
        if(!string || isNaN(+(string))){
          throw new Error('yootil.Utilities.stringToNumber expects a valid number string "123.45" )');
        }
        
        decimal_places = (decimal_places === 0) ? 0 : (decimal_places) || 2;
        
        return +(parseFloat(string).toFixed(decimal_places));
        
      }catch(e){ console.error(e); console.log(string); return null;} 
    }
  }
  
  return module;
  
}(yootil = yootil || {}));

exports.yootil = yootil;
```

Comment: In Test 3, you're rounding a number with four decimals to four decimal places -- everything I see here should pass, as it is. Did you mean Test 2?

Comment: Hey Cory. I was under the assumption `Test 3` would round to  `123.4600`  ?

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ Test 2 should also pass, as if no `decimal_places` argument is given it becomes `2` because of `|| 2` bit.

Comment: @VisioN Yes it does set a default of 2 places. All test's do pass, I was just curious as to why `test 3` was not rounding up to `123.4600`. In my mind at least how I thought it would round up.

Comment: Test three is passing a `4` for `decimal_places` parameter, so it's rounding to 4 decimal places, not 2.

Comment: @Philip Yeah, but why should it round up to `.4600` if you have `123.4587` as a number and `4` decimal places as argument? If you do `parseFloat("123.4587")` for string, you'll get `123.4587` as float, then `.toFixed(4)` won't do anything with it except transform it back to string `"123.4587"`, whereas `+"123.4587"` will return the same float number. I don't see if something may go wrong here.

Comment: Also, out of curiosity, why `.toFixed()` instead of `Math.round()`?

Comment: Yeah I guess you guys are both right, my thinking was flawed, rather than the code itself. Thank you.

Comment: With all this, just keep in mind that you will have strange cases where floating-point numbers round one way or another. One one computer, `new Number(123.4585).toFixed(0)` might return `124` and on others it might return `123`.

Comment: @Cory I am not sure how `Math.round()` implementation would work on decimal places ?!  Thanks for the insights!